# Use of super() with not immediate parent

Tags: python, super

Is this a legal use of super()?

```
class A(object):
    def method(self, arg):
        pass

class B(A):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(B,self).method(arg)

class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(B,self).method(arg)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks valid to me. You might want to read this, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will work, but it will probably confuse anyone trying to read your code (including you, unless you remember it specifically). Don't forget that if you want to call a method from a particular parent class, you can just do:

```
A.method(self, arg)
```

Comment: I assume, if there is no multiple-inheritance involved, both `A.method(self, arg)` and `super(B,self).method(arg)` are equivalent (minus the potential user confusion)?

Comment: @upperBound: Yes. Although obviously in both cases you need to be aware of what happens if you change their inheritance relationships.

Answer (score 3):

Well, "legal" is a questionable term here. The code will end up calling `A.method`, since the type given to `super` is excluded from the search. I would consider this usage of `super` flaky to say the least, since it will skip a member of the inheritance hierarchy (seemingly haphhazardly), which is inconsistent with what I would expect as a developer. Since users of `super` are already encouraged to maintain consistency, I'd recommend against this practice.

Comment: I agree. What do you think about using `A.method(self, arg)` since this too would step over the hierarchy?